# How to find elements in one array which are not in another array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays in Javascript and I would like to find the elements which are in the first array but are absent from the second array. I found a bit of difficulty doing this because the elements are dictionaries.

```js
const array1 = [
    {
    name: 'Emmanuel Buabeng',
    house: '9',
    class: '2H',
    objectID: 0
  
    },
    {
    name: 'Michael Sungnuma',
    house: '9',
    class: '2D3',
    objectID: 1
   
    },
    {
        name: 'David Antwi',
        house: '9',
        class: '2D2',
        objectID: 2
        
    },
    {
        name: 'William Segbedzi',
        house: '9',
        class: '2C',
        objectID: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'Kofi Afriyie',
        house: '9',
        class: '2B2',
        objectID: 4
    }
];
```

This is the second array:

```js
const array2  = [
    {
        name: 'Kofi Afriyie',
        house: '9',
        class: '2B2',
        objectID: 4
    }
];
```

Comment: so what problem are you hitting?

Comment: How have you tried to find them by yourself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could filter the first array and leave only elements which are not present in the second array like this:

```js
const Array1 = [
    { objectID: 0 },
    { objectID: 1 },
    { objectID: 2 },
    { objectID: 3 },
    { objectID: 4 }
];
const Array2 = [
    { objectID: 4 }
];
const diff = Array1.filter(item => Array2.every(i => item.objectID !== i.objectID));
console.log({ diff });
```

If want to reduce a few cycles try checking if currently checking element from first array does not exists in second array like this:

```
const diff = Array1.filter(item => !Array2.some(i => item.objectID === i.objectID));
```